# Why does Null appear in Contract and Pair commands of FeynCalc?

Tags: feyncalc

I started now to use FeynCalc on Mathematica 10. The installation looks like okay, but every time I use Contract or Pair commands the output is something with "Null". Even in this simple case, for a product of two metric tensors, the output appearing is just Pair(Null,Null).  This same simple operation in another computer gives 4, that is the right result. Someone already had this same problem, and know how to solve?
[image: Here I put a print of the problem.]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange. Please get into habit of posting code in copyable form instead of images. This way, people can try to reproduce the problem and to develop a fix.

Comment: Remove `$LoadPhi=True` and it should be fine. PHI is broken anyhow, so currently there is no point to try to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything is working now.